# Adding template literal to HTML element?

Tags: javascript, templates

```
function addthis(){
        var title=document.getElementById("title").value;
        var desc=document.getElementById("desc").value;
        var newRow=document.querySelector('tbody');
        var newbody=`<tr>
                        <td>${title}<td>
                        <td>${desc}</td>
                    </tr>`;
        newRow.append(newbody);
    }
```

I was trying to add new row and inside that this content when user click on add to list but the output is its showing every content as `<tr><td>hello<td><td>title</td></tr>` like this.

what should be the right way to use this

Comment: `newRow.innerHTML += (newbody);` update your code like this.

Comment: @Abdur-RehmanM Modifying `innerHTML` removes event listeners. Better to use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead.

Comment: _"but the output is its showing every content as..."_ - As expected. At least after reading the documentation for `.append()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) will insert [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) objects as [`Text` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text), escaping the HTML.

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead:

```js
function addthis() {
  var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var desc = document.getElementById("desc").value;
  var newRow = document.querySelector('tbody');
  var newbody = `<tr>
                        <td>${title}<td>
                        <td>${desc}</td>
                    </tr>`;
  newRow.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newbody);
}

addthis()
```

```html
<input id="title" value="title">
<input id="desc" value="description">
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```